# NullPointerException in DatagramSocket

Tags: java, sockets, nullpointerexception

I am creating a server chat program in java using DatagramSocket and datagramPacket
im getting a java.lang.NullPointerException in client code to send data packet

```
try
{
    InetAddress ia = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
    String s1 = new String(Uname + "-C-" + ia.getHostAddress());
    cdp = new DatagramPacket(s1.getBytes(), s1.length(), ia, 7080);
    csock.send(cdp);
    csock.setSoTimeout(5000);
    csock.receive(cdp);
    s1 = new String(cdp.getData(), 0, cdp.getLength());
    chat.append(s1);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    onlineuser.append("\n" + e);
}
```

Can someone help me to clear this bug.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you walk through with a debugger to isolate the exact line that is giving you the exception and let us know?

Comment: Yes you get an error. and what's your question? Something like: how to solve my problem?

Comment: What is the state of the variables just before the null pointer exception?

Comment: In Java don't use new when creating a String, declare a string like this: String s1 = Uname+"-C-"+ia.getHostAddress();

Comment: @BlackVegetable ya after csock.send(cdp) .im getting java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Can you show us where you initialize your csock?  It helps to have the exact code that you think is relevant in Stack Overflow.  (But try not to go overboard and submit your entire program!)

Comment: I'm sorry @MichaelShopsin could you be more specific about which variable . well  the DatagramPacket and DatagramSocket are just declared in constructor.

Comment: The stacktrace should give you a solid hint of where the NPE occures. Otherwise you could use the Eclipse debugger and set a Java Exception Break on NPEs. This way the debugger would stop right when the NPE occurs.

Comment: @BlackVegetable        public class ClConnect  implements ActionListener{ public DatagramSocket csock;

Comment: @ user1475089 and where is initialization of csock ? Am I right csock is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you told us in your comments, you aren't initializing csock.  Be sure to call its constructor before attempting to use it.

You have declared it by saying: public DatagramSocket csock;  but you haven't assigned it any value, and thus it defaults to null.  That is the source of your exception.

Comment: And where is diff between our answers, or you decided to explain my answe in more words ?

Comment: Ah, I assumed the user was new to OO programming and needed to know to use a constructor.  However, if you would like you can include this in your answer and I will delete mine.

Comment: Thank you . i never noticed that initialization part.i owe u.

Comment: It is not a problem of OOP its a problem of start developing without reading any docs. It's sad ...

Answer (score 0):

you did not provide enough code for analyze but I think `csock`is null. 
for more information try to read [this docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/clientServer.html)